# .htaccess not rewriting filenames

Tags: htaccess

I'm not sure whether this is a Craft problem or whether I'm just not seeing something wrong.

For a test site with a folder structure like:

```
public
  assets
     css
```

I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^assets/(js|css)/(.+)\.\w+\.(js|css)$ assets/$1/$2.$3 [L,NC]
```

which works fine in that

```
/assets/css/test.css
/assets/css/test.min.css
/assets/css/test.jhd8jdjdj.min.css
```

all resolve to the same file.

But on a Craft site whose directory structure is

```
public
  _css
  _js
```

this results in a 404

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(_js|_css)/(.+)\.\w+\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.$3 [L,NC]
```

for

```
/_css/test.min.css
/_css/test.jhd8jdjdj.min.css
```

Both sites are running locally on MAMP using Apache.

So is this a problem specific to Craft? Or can I just not see what's wrong with the rewrite rules on the Craft site?

The full `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Asset path rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(_js|_css)/(.+)\.\w+\.(js|css)$ $1/$2.$3 [L,NC]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

There's actually a bunch of HTML5 Boilerplate stuff in there as well but the output is the same with or without it.

Comment: Can you post the ``.htaccess`` file in question? BTW your rules should go above the default Craft rules in the file…

Comment: @RitterKnight I've edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 2):

Craft doesn’t get involved in .htaccess redirects at all, so whatever it is, it’s going to be a server config thing.

Some things to check:

- Is this server actually using Apache and not Nginx?
- Is `AllowOverride` enabled? (The Apache config that allows .htaccess files)
- Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned in the original question that both sites are running locally on MAMP using Apache.